# Postgresql - SQL to Update a JSONB column type

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a table which has a column named "data" of type JSONB. I am trying to come up with a SQL statement to accomoodate the recent model changes. (postgres 9.4)

"isIndiaGSTComposition" in old model needs to be changed as "auxiliaryProperties" data structure (below) in the new model.

```
 {  
   "test":{  
      "isIndiaGSTComposition":true        (boolean)
   }
}
```

New model :

```
{  
   "test":{  
      "AuxiliaryProperties":[
                   {
                    "id":"indiaGSTComposition",
                    "booleanValue":true
                    }
                  ]        
   }
}
```

Please note that, if isIndiaGSTComposition is null, it should be auxiliaryProperties : null. But if it has true or false, it needs to be in the above data structure format(like in "new model" example above).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can write conversion function and use

```
UPDATE table
SET field = conv_func(field);
```

All JSON operations are [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) (choose your PostgreSQL version).

Use `json->'test'` operator to get subobject of 'test':

```
{  
      "isIndiaGSTComposition":true        (boolean)
}
```

If you have multiple fields, you can iterate over them with

```
FOR _rec IN
SELECT t."key", t."value"
FROM jsonb_each(subobject) t
LOOP
...
END LOOP;
```

Declare new JSONB variable for new `"AuxiliaryProperties"` subobject and init it with `'{}'::jsonb`

Use `jsonb_insert()` to populate `"AuxiliaryProperties"` with `"id"` and `"booleanValue"`.

Then use `jsonb_insert()` again to insert new subobject with key `"AuxiliaryProperties"` and use `#-` operator to delete old subobject.